# Apex Replay Debugger: list of size x too large to display

Tags: apex, vs-code, debugging, b2b-commerce, apex-replay-debugger

I am trying to debug an Apex Class for Salesforce B2B Commerce. In this class I am querying the `Order Delivery Method` records but when I try to see these records in the debugger it says `list of size 7 too large to display`.

I have already added checkpoints on the applicable lines. The debug log level is set to FINEST for apex code and profiling. The checkpoints are updated in the Org.

As per my understanding, if I use checkpoints I should be able to see the data present in List or Map data structures.

Sample Code

```
String a = 'Hello'; // added checkpoint 1
List<OrderDeliveryMethod> allODMs = [Select Id, Carrier, Name from OrderDeliveryMethod where isActive = true]; // added checkpoint 2
String b = 'World'; // added checkpoint 3
```

Debug Level

`57.0 APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,FINEST;CALLOUT,FINEST;DB,FINEST;NBA,FINE;SYSTEM,FINE;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,FINER;WAVE,FINEST;WORKFLOW,FINER`

So, what am I missing here?